# int values with string values in enum

Tags: java, enums

How can I make cards Enum in Java similar to:

```
public enum Card {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
```

I tried {"2", "3"...}. It's not working either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The JLS (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) tells us two important facts:

1. [Java enum fields must be valid identifiers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)

   ```
   EnumConstants:
       EnumConstant
       EnumConstants , EnumConstant

   EnumConstant:
       Annotations_opt Identifier Arguments_opt ClassBody_opt

   Arguments:
       ( ArgumentList_opt )

   EnumBodyDeclarations:
       ; ClassBodyDeclarations_opt
   ```
2. [The first character of an identifier must be a "Java letter."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

   > <sup>*The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters `A-Z` (`\u0041`-`\u005a`), and `a-z` (`\u0061`-`\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`) and dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`). The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.*</sup>

You must work within these restrictions.

```
public enum Card {
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen, 
    King,
    Ace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must try using valid identifiers ie `TWO, THREE, FOUR`, 2,3,4 are not valid here.